# Golang Changeable field

Tags: json, go, variables, struct, field

I'd like to know that is possible to make a changeable struct for golang.
Here is the thing.
there are the different objects of JSON.
It contains "meta" always, but "data" will be changed like below.

```
{"meta":{"A":"AA, "B":"BB"}, "data":{"C":"CC"}}
{"meta":{"A":"DD, "B":"EE"}, "data":{"F":"FF"}}
```

In my golang code, there is so many structs for JSON like below.

```
type meta struct {
    A  string  `json:"A"`
    B float64 `json:"B"`
}

type data1 struct {
    C int64 `json:"C"`
}

type JSON1 struct {
    MetaData meta `json:"meta"`
    Contents data1 `json:"data"`
}

type data2 struct {
    C int64 `json:"F"`
}

type JSON2 struct {
    MetaData meta `json:"meta"`
    Contents data2 `json:"data"`
}
```

So, I need to define all the struct.
Is there any way to make the Contents field is changeable to reduce JSON"A", "B" definitions?

Thanks for the reply in advance.

Comment: Try `Contents interface{} \`json:"data"\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map[string]interface{}`

```golang
type JSON struct {
    MetaData meta                   `json:"meta"`
    Contents map[string]interface{} `json:"data"`
}
```

and then access data like:

```
var d JSON
...
content, ok := d.Contents["F"] // ok is false if "F" is not present
```